# Почему foreach (opencart) выдаёт только последний результат?

Tags: php, mvc, framework, opencart, foreach

Всех приветствую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Пытаюсь вывести меню следующего вида:
-Категория 1
---производитель 2
---производитель 6
-Категория 2
---производитель 3
---производитель 5
---производитель 2
-Категория 3
---производитель 1

т.е. под категорией должны появиться производители, содержащиеся в ней. 
И почти всё получается, кроме одного - во всех категориях выводятся производители, принадлежащие последней категории.

В контроллере это выглядит так:

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      if ($category['top']) {


                // Level 2
        $children_data = array(); //1

        $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']); //2

        foreach ($children as $child) { //3
          $filter_data = array(
            'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
            'filter_sub_category' => true
          );

          $children_data[] = array(
            'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
          );
        }

        // Level 1
        $data['categories'][] = array(
          'name'     => $category['name'],
          'children' => $children_data,
          'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
          'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
        );


                //manufacturers menu

                $manufacturers = $this->model_catalog_category->getManufacturers($category['category_id']); //2

                $data['manufacturers'] = array(); //1
                foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer)  { //3
                       $data['manufacturers'][] = array (
                       'manufacturer_id' => $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'],
                       'thumb' => $manufacturer['image'],
                       'name' => $manufacturer['name'],
                       'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '&manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'])
                        );
                }


      }
    }
```

В view так:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <b><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></b> <br> 
            <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
                     ----    <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href'] ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name'] ?> (<?php echo $manufacturer['thumb'] ?>)</a> <br>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Если аналогичным образом делаю для level 2- всё отлично работает. С производителями - никак =(

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

upd 1 
Модель такая:

```
public function getManufacturers($filter_category_id = 0, $filter_sub_category = false) {

                        if($filter_category_id == 0) $filter_sub_category = true;

                        $sql = "SELECT m.name, m.manufacturer_id, m.image ";
                        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ";

                        $sql .= " INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p.manufacturer_id=m.manufacturer_id)";
                            if ($filter_sub_category == true) {
                                $implode_data = array();
                                $categories = $this->getCategoriesByParentId($filter_category_id);
                                $categories[]=$filter_category_id;
                                $implode_data = implode(',',$categories);
                                $sql .= " INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p.`product_id`=p2c.`product_id`) and p2c.`category_id` in (".$implode_data.")";
                            } else {
                                $sql .= " INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p.`product_id`=p2c.`product_id`) and p2c.`category_id`=".$filter_category_id."";
                            }
                        $sql .= " GROUP BY p.manufacturer_id";


                        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                        return $query->rows;

                    }
```

Comment: getManufacturers - метод ваш или это какой-то шаблон?

Answer (score 0):

Лично я с opencart не работал, но могу предложить вам решение.

Судя по проблеме `$categories` это результат работы `mysql_fetch_assoc` (или аналога).

Он удаляет одну строчку из запроса и отдаёт её.

Это можно легко исправить:

```
while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    /* что-то */
}
```

P.S. `$query` это результат запроса

Comment: Хм, но ведь дочерние категории выводит... Да и в модели нигде не нашёл mysql_fetch_assoc... В пост добавлю модель, чтобы больше информации было =)

Comment: Как я понял opencart это что-то типо фреймворка и `mysql_fetch_assoc` вы не найдёте. Это надо смотреть документацию

Answer (score 0):

Метод модели, который вы используете что бы собрать производителей по категории, видимо написан под фильтр своей(кастомной) темы. Напишите свой метод модели на основе запроса:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name
FROM prefix_manufacturer m, prefix_product p, prefix_product_to_category p2c
WHERE p2c.category_id = $category_id
AND p.product_id = p2c.product_id
AND p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id;
```

Запрос проверен на OC2, вернёт массив (`$query->rows()`) производителей в категории `$category_id`